# wicked_pdf without yield content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true%>
```

```
def show
  @invoice_items = @invoice.accounts_receivables_items

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :template => "invoices/show"}
    format.pdf  {render :pdf => "invoices/show",
                        :template => 'layouts/application.html', formats: :html, encoding: 'utf8', :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?}
  end
end
```

I get this. It's my webpage (layout/application.html) but without the `<%= yield %>` content

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you specified `:template` to be your layout file, it is rendering your layout without a view.

How about something more like this (notice the template and layout keys):

```
render pdf: "invoice",
       layout: 'layouts/application.html',
       template: 'invoices/show',
       formats: :html,
       encoding: 'utf8',
       show_as_html: params[:debug].present?
```

Comment: @sparkle Are you perhaps using some kind of non-standard font or font library that could be doing this?

Comment: Yes, Fixed. I've replaced every asset_path() with asset_url() in my css which they were refering to fonts, and I have set  config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://website.com/" in my enviroment